# Why is axios returning a wrap function?

Tags: javascript, axios

axios is returning wrap function but I want to use *axios.CancelToken* in it. Any idea on why this is happening?

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: appUrl,
  timeout: 0,
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config) {
    console.log(instance);
  }
);

export const $axios = instance;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CancelToken`](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) is a static property of `axios`. It's not an instance property.

If you're using ES6 module imports, an easy way to reference it is by importing it

```js
import axios, { CancelToken } from "axios"

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: appUrl,
  timeout: 0,
});

const source = CancelToken.source()

instance.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
})

// cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
source.cancel("Operation cancelled by the user.");
```

This is really just a shorter version of

```js
import axios from "axios"
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
```

Comment: Yea...I figured it out but somehow before, static property also didn't work. Now it is working.